# Python: Parse JSON data to csv file

Tags: python-3.x

How do I parse "this line" data out in Python3 and the rest as csv one line.
CSV file data should look like this:
this line;Value;Description

```
{
  "this line": {
    "Value": "8",
    "Description": "Description",
  },
{
  "this line2": {
    "Value": "9",
    "Description": "Description",
  },
```

I have try to read it as i standard json but cant get the "this line" row out.

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: I whant to save it as a csv file.
Output like this
Thisline;Value;Description

Comment: that can be whatever, thats the hard part

Answer (score 1):

You use this example how to write the data to a csv file:

```py
import csv

data = {
    "this line": {
        "Value": "8",
        "Description": "Description",
    },
    "this line2": {
        "Value": "9",
        "Description": "Description",
    },
}

with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=';')

    # write header
    writer.writerow(['Line', 'Value', 'Description'])

    for k, v in data.items():
        writer.writerow([k, v.get('Value'), v.get('Description')])
```

creates `data.csv` with content:

```
Line;Value;Description
this line;8;Description
this line2;9;Description
```